# Testing Remove method without a call to Add method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I am writing test for a class thats manage trees of Tag objects:

```
public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description{ get; set; }
    private IList<Tag> children = new List<Tag>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Tag> Children
    {
        get {return children .ToArray();}
    }
    public void AddChildTag(Tag child)
    {
        children.Add(child);
    }
    public void RemoveChildTag(Tag child)
    {
        children.Remove(child);
    }
}
```

As you can see the only mode to set the parent property is via the `AddChildTag` method and this is exactly what i want, my problem is in unit test: since every test should be atomic, how can i test the `RemoveChildTag` method?

Only way i see is a call to the add method and later to the remove, but in this way if Add as some errors, even the test of remove will fail, so atomicity is lost.

How can that be done?

**EDIT**
I removed parent property from Tag object, since i no more use it
Some test according to solution using NUnit and FluentAssertion

```
    [Test]
    public void AddChildTagAddsChildren()
    {
        //Arrange
        Tag parent = new Tag();
        Tag child = new Tag();
        //Act
        parent.AddChildTag(child);
        //Assert
        parent.Children.Should().Contain(child);
    }
    [Test]
    public void RemoveChildTagRemovesAddedChildren()
    {
        //Arrange
        Tag parent = new Tag();
        Tag child = new Tag();
        parent.AddChildTag(child);
        //Act
        parent.RemoveChildTag(child);
        //Assert
        parent.Children.Should().NotContain(child);
    }
    [Test]
    public void RemoveChildTagThrowsNothingWhenNoChild()
    {
        //Arrange
        Tag parent= new Tag();
        Tag child= new Tag();
        //Act
        Action RemoveChild = () => parent.RemoveChildTag(child);
        //Assert
        RemoveChild.ShouldNotThrow();
    }
```

Comment: Slight side-note: It is also worth testing the behavior of calling `Remove` without calling `Add` to test that either no exception is thrown or the correct exception is thrown with the correct state.

Comment: Since remove depends on `add`, if the test passes you know that `if add works, then remove works`. Once `add` is tested, you then know `remove` works.

Comment: @Jonny, correct see my comment on Lukazoid answer

Comment: question updated with some tests

Comment: Your tests look fine. With Fluent, I suggest giving more contextual name to `act` action variable (`act.ShouldNotThrow()` vs `removeChildTag.ShouldNotThrow()`).

Comment: good suggestion. name edited

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your unit tests should reflect *actual* use cases of your class. How will your consumers use `RemoveChildTag` method? Which makes more sense? Which is how you'd use collection of objects?

```
var parent = new Tag();
// later
parent.RemoveChildTag(child);
```

… or

```
var parent = new Tag();
parent.AddChildTag(child);
// later
parent.RemoveChildTag(child);
```

Your consumers will remove objects they **previously added**. This is your use case, *"Remove removes elements previously added"* (note that it also produces excellent test method name).

`Add` and `Remove` methods are often complementary - you can't test one without the other.

Comment: @gt.guybrush I think only this aswer can be the correct answer, break the incapsulation for testing purpose are not the correct approach

Answer (score 14):

There are some ways to test `Remove` method:

1. Mocking - mock your data structure, and call remove , so you can test calling the right methods
2. Inheritance - make `children` protected. Your test class will inherit from `Tag` class. Now you can init `children` member so we can test the remove
3. Use `Add` Method

I think option 3 is the best, it's ok using other methods in your unit testing, if `Add` have some error , more then 1 test will fail - you should be able to understand what you need to fix.

Also, each unit test should test some basic behavior, even if you need to do some preparation before.
If those preparation failed, fail the test with the relevant comments

**Option 1**  - is best when you code is reaching to 3rd party - other server, file system & more. Since you don't want to make those calls in unit test - mock the response.

**Option 2** - best I can say , is when you want to test protected / private method, without needing to make all the calls "on the way" that your code does (public method that make many calls that eventually call the method you want to test), since you want to test only a specific logic. It also easy to use this option when your class have some state that you want to test, without needing to write a lot of code to bring your class to this state.

Comment: i mark jimmy_keen naswer as solution just for naming example of method test. If I could mark two answers also would mark your (i simply can add a +1)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [PrivateObject Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) to *Arrange* your object under test

> Allows test code to call methods and properties on the code under test
>   that would be inaccessible because they are not public.

**EDIT**

then you could get full access to wrapped object by [PrivateObject.RealType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.realtype.aspx) and  [PrivateObject.Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.target.aspx) Properties

**EDIT**

Anyway, every system which break the segregation and encapsulation of a class make useless the black box approach of Unit Testing in TDD and should be avoided as a poison :)

Comment: This can cause to have your application behave in a different flow. Via this way the child.parent is not set and could lead to other errors. (probably not in this case, but in others it might)

Comment: @RvdK you are completely right, anyway a PrivateObject give the possibility to do what requested without the need of complex reflection mocking operations

Comment: i give it a try: PrivateObject po = new PrivateObject(typeof(Tag)); po.SetProperty("Parent", parent); but now how can i cast this object to a tag need as parameter to call the remove method?

Comment: thanks, i agree to your (and other user) notes about the encapsulation break. i gave it a try to learn a new things (and i have to say that don't like the need of magic strings) but i will mark mzf or jimmy_keen answer as solution. i add +1 to yours

Comment: @gt.guybrush I agree your decision :)

Answer (score 2):

A common approach to unit testing is the Arrange-Act-Assert paradigm.

I would personally have two tests for the remove method, one which is removing a child which was never added, what should happen? Should an exception be thrown?

This would look like:

```
[Test]
public void RemoveChildTagThrowsExceptionWhenNoChildren()
{
    // Arrange
    var tag = new Tag();
    var tagToRemove = new Tag();

    // Act & Assert
    Expect(() => tag.RemoveChildTag(tagToRemove), Throws.ArgumentException);
}
```

Then I would have another test for what should happen when an added child is removed:

```
[Test]
public void RemoveChildTagRemovesPreviouslyAddedChild()
{
    // Arrange
    var tag = new Tag();
    var childTag = new Tag();
    tag.AddChildTag(childTag);

    // Act
    tag.RemoveChildTag(childTag);

    // Assert
    Expect(tag.Children.Contains(childTag), Is.False);
}
```

It may be of interest to note that quite a lot of .NET `Remove` implementations return a bool result which indicates whether any removal was actually performed. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bye7h94w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: i use a similar sintax but with Nunit and FluentAssertion (sintax more readable: tag.Children.Should().NotContain(childTag)). the bool return is interesting but why not even the add? For the first case i prefer not throw exception, simply i do nothing